# I would like others to explain phone number from contact to textbox

Tags: android

i try this:

```
public class CallMEActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

     Button btnPress;
     EditText txtPhoneNo;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        btnPress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPress);
        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);

        btnPress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {  
                Intent i = new
                Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                i.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
                int request_Code = 0;
                startActivityForResult(i,request_Code);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        try {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();

                Cursor cur = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                ContentResolver contect_resolver = getContentResolver();

                if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    String id = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    Cursor phoneCur = contect_resolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                    if (phoneCur.moveToFirst()) {

                        txtPhoneNo.setText(phoneCur
                                .getString(phoneCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));



                    }

                    id = null;

                    phoneCur = null;
                }
                contect_resolver = null;
                cur = null;
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

i press the button, and pick one contacts -> but the textbox still empty

i run it with debug and i see that `cur` is empty

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

on the button onClick

```
Intent i = new
Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_PICK);
i.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.C ONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(i,request_Code);
```

then create a method paste below code and do accordingly.

The idea is you opened an ContactActivity for getting the infomation.So when you pick a contact onActivityResult will be fired automatically.So you have to find the number there and have to put in textbox

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        try {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();

                Cursor cur = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                ContentResolver contect_resolver = getContentResolver();

                if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    String id = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    Cursor phoneCur = contect_resolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                    if (phoneCur.moveToFirst()) {

                        txtPhoneNo.setText(phoneCur
                                .getString(phoneCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));



                    }

                    id = null;

                    phoneCur = null;
                }
                contect_resolver = null;
                cur = null;
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the help !! i'am new in android, where to put this code ? 
i have button that do the code that i write

Comment: thanks for the help, but after i press the button the textbox is empty. what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, too.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_PICK_CONTACT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String strName = "";
        String strPhone = "";

        Uri dataUri = data.getData();
        Cursor contacts = managedQuery(dataUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (contacts.moveToFirst()) {
            String name;
            int nameColumn = contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
            name = contacts.getString(nameColumn);
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(dataUri, null, null, null, null);
            if (phones.moveToFirst()) {
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                strName = new String(name);
                strPhone = new String(phoneNumber);
            }
            phones.close();
        }

        EditText edtName = (EditText) mParentsAddDialog.findViewById(R.id.edt_add_parents_name);
        EditText edtPhone = (EditText) mParentsAddDialog.findViewById(R.id.edt_add_parents_phone);

        edtName.setText(strName);
        edtPhone.setText(strPhone);
    }
}
```